# Drawing with c++ visual studio 2010 beta?

Tags: c++, windows

please tell me how to draw any shape (a small square e.g) 
using visual studio 2010 with the c++ language ?
PUT THEM STEP BY STEP PLEASE
I don't know what type of file i have to choose nor how to check it out

Comment: This is not a C++ question.  C++ has no support for drawing anything.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: Good thing "computer" was tagged. I was almost going to suggest getting a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean drawing in win32? I would suggest you to check this out:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/paint_beginner.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are requesting to draw with ANSI C++ (non-managed).

With OpenGL you would:

1. Setup the dependencies in your project
2. Set up the framework for creating the Window
3. Setup the function call back methods
4. Use vectors to draw the shapes using basic components of the shapes

Take a look at this [OpenGL tutorial in C++.](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/opengl_introduction.html)